# How to force a file to download mp3 instead of opening

Tags: javascript, php, html, download

I have a website that contains a lot of mp3 files, and I'd like the user to be able to download the mp3 file by simply using the direct link. For example, one song that I have is located:

http://www.mywebsite.com/song1.mp3

How can I set up my website so that when the user accesses the direct link, the mp3 is downloaded to their computer, and the mp3 doesn't open in the browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to you I found a pretty cool trick :)

```
<a href="1.mp3" download>mysong</a>
```

Comment: `download` attribute is not supported in all the browsers.

Comment: it is supported in [chrome and firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)